# wp_pagenavi doesn't work with WP_Query from page2

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

wp_pagenavi doesn't work from page 2.

**[OK]**  url/wordpress/**2013/06/**

**[NG. 404 error occured]**  url/wordpress/**2013/06/page/2/**

I tried some plugins, but nothing changed.

This is my code.

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    ......
);
$myquery = new WP_Query($args);

<?php if ($myquery->have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while ($myquery->have_posts()): $myquery->the_post(); ?>

            /* Do stuff */

            <?php endwhile; ?>

wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $myquery));

<?php endif; ?>
```

Default query works fine in the other page(loop.php).

- Wordpress 3.5.1
- WP-PageNavi 2.83

Tried plugins are

- Top Level Categories Fix
- Custom Post Type Category Pagination Fix

Does anyone know anything?